# Are locusts parve?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

One of my friends is Sephardi. He eats locusts, sometimes.

I know that locusts are categorized as שרצים - "creeping things" and are not in the same category as the other kosher animals that need to be ruminants and with split hooves.

But I wanted some clarity on whether they are automatically considered parve, as well and if the reason is because they are in their own category.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fish and locusts are Pareve. [Shulchan Arukh YD 87:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.87.3?with=all&lang=bi)

Answer (score 1):

See the question I asked: [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89388/16706)
And see the answers, quoting beginning of Rambam הלכות שחיטה and that their ‘killing’ process is comparable to that of a fish. And we know fish are in a fish category and are nonetheless pareve. I would assume that carries over.